# Align images as thumbnails inside a div

Tags: html, css

Here's how it looks like on the [website](http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/apartment-for-sale-in-jbeil/)

Here's the code

```css
div#main-pic {
    padding: 7px 7px 0;
}
.content_res div.bigleft {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 40%; /*240px*/
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

div#thumbs-pic {
    padding: 7px;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a.post-gallery img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigleft">
   <div id="main-pic">
      <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/809926-440x800.jpeg" class="img-main cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/809926-440x800.jpeg" title="1492443192175" alt="1492443192175"></a>
      <div class="clr"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="thumbs-pic">
      <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/462104-480x800.jpg" id="thumb1" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 1"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/462104-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9691" title="IMG_9691" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 1;"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/808110-600x800.jpg" id="thumb2" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 2"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/808110-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9694" title="IMG_9694" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 1;"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/876022-600x800.jpg" id="thumb3" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 3"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/876022-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9690" title="IMG_9690" width="200" height="200"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/823734-600x800.jpg" id="thumb4" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 4"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/823734-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9692" title="IMG_9692" width="200" height="200"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/246168-600x800.jpg" id="thumb5" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 5"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/246168-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9685" title="IMG_9685" width="200" height="200"></a>
      <div class="clr"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is two things:

- Remove the grey container of the pictures. I couldn't find it in inspect element
- I don't want to touch the `#main-pic`, I just want to align all `#thumbs-pic` As thumbnails beneath the `main-pic` horizontally like this

[image]

I know that if i remove

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a.post-gallery img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Half of the problem would be solved, I just don't know how to solve the other half. I tried `display-block` and stuff like that, couldn't get the exact result

Comment: By 'grey container', do you mean the grey background on your website? In that case, that's the background color of the `body` element itself. For lining thumbnails horizontally, `display : inline-block` would be better than simply `display : block`

Comment: @Tijmen no, not that, the gey directly behind the pictures

Comment: Would you have any restrictions to using `flex` or do you need support for IE10 and below?

Comment: @jfeferman you could use whatever you want no problem, my only problem is that I can't edit html, only css. If html must be edited then it has to be done using js/jquery since I html is dynamically generated by wordpress and it's so hard to locate the functions which generate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. First set `display:flex` on `div#thumbs-pic`. Assign the images or flex-item inside this flexbox an appropriate width (I used 82px).  The grey background is in `.content_res div.bigleft`. I changed it to transparent and used the !important declaration to ensure it is not overridden elsewhere. The html is unchanged. Here's the full snippet:

```css
div#main-pic {
    padding: 7px 7px 0;
}
.content_res div.bigleft {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 40%; /*240px*/
 background-color: transparent !important;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

div#thumbs-pic {
    padding: 7px;
    display:flex
}

div#thumbs-pic img {
  width:84px;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a.post-gallery img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigleft">
   <div id="main-pic">
      <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/809926-440x800.jpeg" class="img-main cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/809926-440x800.jpeg" title="1492443192175" alt="1492443192175"></a>
      <div class="clr"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="thumbs-pic">
      <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/462104-480x800.jpg" id="thumb1" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 1"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/462104-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9691" title="IMG_9691" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 1;"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/808110-600x800.jpg" id="thumb2" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 2"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/808110-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9694" title="IMG_9694" width="200" height="200" style="opacity: 1;"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/876022-600x800.jpg" id="thumb3" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 3"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/876022-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9690" title="IMG_9690" width="200" height="200"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/823734-600x800.jpg" id="thumb4" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 4"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/823734-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9692" title="IMG_9692" width="200" height="200"></a><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/246168-600x800.jpg" id="thumb5" class="post-gallery cboxElement" data-rel="colorbox" title="Apartment For Sale in JBEIL - Image 5"><img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/246168-200x200.jpg" alt="IMG_9685" title="IMG_9685" width="200" height="200"></a>
      <div class="clr"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do in this kind of way:

```
<div id="allimagesholder">
    <div id="mainpic">
        <a href=">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbpiccontainer">
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
        <div class="thumbpiccontainer"><a href="><img src="" ></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#allimagesholder {
    height:300px;
    width:27.4em;
    background-color:white;
}
#mainpic {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0.1em;
}
.thumbpiccontainer {
    height:3em;
    width: 3em;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0.1em;
    display:inline-block;
}
.thumbpiccontainer img {

    height:3em;
    width: 3em;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0.1em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: my only problem is that I can't edit html, only css. If html must be edited then it has to be done using js/jquery since I html is dynamically generated by wordpress and it's so hard to locate the functions which generate it